# Three part chess problem

Tags: cipher, chess, alphametic

Three separate puzzles:

```
a) White to play and mate in 4 (You can ignore the line)
b) Replace each kind of figurine with a digit to make a correct addition sum
c) Replace each kind of figurine piece with a letter to make the original
```

[image: 8/8/3QPpK1/3rRNP1/2rRpPk1/8/8/8 w - - 0 1]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Answer

Mate in 4 moves:

> 1. Qa3 Rc3 2. Qxc3 e3 3. Qxe3 (any move) 4. Qg3#

Answer for the cryptarithm:

> $9567 + 1085 = 10652$.

That is, using the FEN notation,

> $\\Q = 9,\\ P = 5,\\ p = 6,\\ K = 7,\\ r = 1,\\ R = 0,\\ N = 8,\\ k = 2$

The third part means:

> SEND + MORE = MONEY which is the original cryptarithm

Comment: Hmm, I was wondering if it was 4 ply or 4 plyply... looks like my first guess was correct

Comment: Black moves 1 & 2 might be transposed, otherwise this is great :)

Comment: Yeah, any way Queen will win both the pieces. Yeah, in your view, losing a piece of relatively smaller value first is emphasized. It is great too @Laska

Comment: I don't see how you got the third part?

Comment: The third part refers to “an original”, this is a famous cryptarithm (the first?) by the legendary puzzle-maker H.E.Dudeney so yes it’s more of a general knowledge question but I think it complements the other two parts, and the solver got it